# How to open new activity not with the position but with the name?

Tags: android

What I want is that to address a new activity is taken into account the name and not the position, for example here I have two names "Ciclismo" and "Correr" and here the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lista;
ArrayList<Datos> arraydatos = new ArrayList<Datos>();
Datos datos;
adapterdatos adapter = new adapterdatos(this, arraydatos);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_lista);


    datos = new Datos(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ciclistapng), "Ciclismo", "Imagen de tipo PNG");
    arraydatos.add(datos);
    datos = new Datos(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corredor), "Correr", "Imagen de tipo PNG");
    arraydatos.add(datos);


    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lista);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MainActivity.super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_context_menu, menu);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent ci = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ciclismo.class);
                    startActivity(ci);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ciclismo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_id:
            arraydatos.remove(info.position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.añadir_id:
            arraydatos.add(datos);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Añadido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return MainActivity.super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

I want it in case not for its position but for its name in the listview. Thank you and forgive my english.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that when an item is clicked in ListView you want to fetch it through name and not by position. Correct me if wrong. ListView click is normally obtained through position, but you can get view name by setting tag in listview items.

Comment: Yes, you're fine, all this is because I want to send these elements to other listview so I want these elements to preserve the activity that each opens.